# Newbie programmer writing Python function to iterate through a list and merge results

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am a newbie programmer. I am trying to think of a function or loop that I could write to automate this code so that it will iterate through a list of URLs of any size, and then merge them. This is how I've written it out so far, now I need to think of a way to make this more efficient. Any help getting going on a writing a function would be much appreciated.

```
url1_analysis = return_entity_dataframe(response1)
url2_analysis = return_entity_dataframe(response2)
url3_analysis = return_entity_dataframe(response3)
url4_analysis = return_entity_dataframe(response4)
url5_analysis = return_entity_dataframe(response5)
url6_analysis = return_entity_dataframe(response6)
url7_analysis = return_entity_dataframe(response7)
url8_analysis = return_entity_dataframe(response8)
url9_analysis = return_entity_dataframe(response9)
url10_analysis = return_entity_dataframe(response10)
url11_analysis = return_entity_dataframe(response11)
url12_analysis = return_entity_dataframe(response12)
url13_analysis = return_entity_dataframe(response13)
url14_analysis = return_entity_dataframe(response14)
url15_analysis = return_entity_dataframe(response15)
url16_analysis = return_entity_dataframe(response16)
url17_analysis = return_entity_dataframe(response17)
url18_analysis = return_entity_dataframe(response18)
url19_analysis = return_entity_dataframe(response19)
url20_analysis = return_entity_dataframe(response20)
url21_analysis = return_entity_dataframe(response21)
url22_analysis = return_entity_dataframe(response22)
url23_analysis = return_entity_dataframe(response23)
url24_analysis = return_entity_dataframe(response24)
url25_analysis = return_entity_dataframe(response25)
url26_analysis = return_entity_dataframe(response26)
url27_analysis = return_entity_dataframe(response27)
url28_analysis = return_entity_dataframe(response28)

url1and2 = url1_analysis.merge(url2_analysis,how='outer', left_on='entity_name', right_on="entity_name")
url1and2and3 = url1and2.merge(url3_analysis,how='outer', left_on='entity_name', right_on="entity_name")
url1and2and3and4 = url1and2and3.merge(url4_analysis,how='outer', left_on='entity_name', right_on="entity_name")
url1and2and3and4and5 = url1and2and3and4.merge(url5_analysis,how='outer', left_on='entity_name', right_on="entity_name")
url1and2and3and4and5and6 = url1and2and3and4and5.merge(url6_analysis,how='outer', left_on='entity_name', right_on="entity_name")
url1and2and3and4and5and6and7 = url1and2and3and4and5and6.merge(url7_analysis,how='outer', left_on='entity_name', right_on="entity_name")
url1and2and3and4and5and6and7and8 = url1and2and3and4and5and6and7.merge(url8_analysis,how='outer', left_on='entity_name', right_on="entity_name")
url1and2and3and4and5and6and7and8and9 = url1and2and3and4and5and6and7and8.merge(url9_analysis,how='outer', left_on='entity_name', right_on="entity_name")
url1and2and3and4and5and6and7and8and9and10 = url1and2and3and4and5and6and7and8and9.merge(url10_analysis,how='outer', left_on='entity_name', right_on="entity_name")
url1and2and3and4and5and6and7and8and9and10and11 = url1and2and3and4and5and6and7and8and9and10.merge(url11_analysis,how='outer', left_on='entity_name', right_on="entity_name")
url1and2and3and4and5and6and7and8and9and10and11and12 = url1and2and3and4and5and6and7and8and9and10and11.merge(url12_analysis,how='outer', left_on='entity_name', right_on="entity_name")
url1and2and3and4and5and6and7and8and9and10and11and12and13 = url1and2and3and4and5and6and7and8and9and10and11and12.merge(url13_analysis,how='outer', left_on='entity_name', right_on="entity_name")
url1and2and3and4and5and6and7and8and9and10and11and12and13and14 = url1and2and3and4and5and6and7and8and9and10and11and12and13.merge(url14_analysis,how='outer', left_on='entity_name', right_on="entity_name")
url1and2and3and4and5and6and7and8and9and10and11and12and13and14and15 = url1and2and3and4and5and6and7and8and9and10and11and12and13and14.merge(url15_analysis,how='outer', left_on='entity_name', right_on="entity_name")
url1and2and3and4and5and6and7and8and9and10and11and12and13and14and15and16 = url1and2and3and4and5and6and7and8and9and10and11and12and13and14and15.merge(url16_analysis,how='outer', left_on='entity_name', right_on="entity_name")
url1and2and3and4and5and6and7and8and9and10and11and12and13and14and15and16and17 = url1and2and3and4and5and6and7and8and9and10and11and12and13and14and15and16.merge(url17_analysis,how='outer', left_on='entity_name', right_on="entity_name")
url1and2and3and4and5and6and7and8and9and10and11and12and13and14and15and16and17and18 = url1and2and3and4and5and6and7and8and9and10and11and12and13and14and15and16and17.merge(url18_analysis,how='outer', left_on='entity_name', right_on="entity_name")
url1and2and3and4and5and6and7and8and9and10and11and12and13and14and15and16and17and18and19 = url1and2and3and4and5and6and7and8and9and10and11and12and13and14and15and16and17and18.merge(url19_analysis,how='outer', left_on='entity_name', right_on="entity_name")
url1and2and3and4and5and6and7and8and9and10and11and12and13and14and15and16and17and18and19and20 = url1and2and3and4and5and6and7and8and9and10and11and12and13and14and15and16and17and18and19.merge(url20_analysis,how='outer', left_on='entity_name', right_on="entity_name")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst_of_responses = [response1, response2, ...] #ideally you create this list automatically.

df_combined = pd.DataFrame()

for response in lst_of_responses:
    df_combined = df_combined.merge(return_entity_dataframe(response), how='outer', on=["entity_name"])
```

If a merge has the same column name for left and right table you can simply say: on=...
Also the moment you try to name variables like variable_name_NUMBER its probably not a good idea. Try using iterables like dictionary, tupels or lists to store the information and process them.